# how to correctly rename an indexed column with alembic & sqlalchemy

Tags: indexing, sqlalchemy, rename, alembic

so..I am perfectly able to rename a column using op.alter_column.

HOWEVER, indices created for that column in the past still reference the old column name!

e.g. Table name is dupe_check. The old column name was 'old_id', and the renamed column is now 'lead_id'. Table info now displays:

KEY `ix_dupe_check_old_id` (`lead_id`),

I don't think this is an issue as it appears there's still an index on the column in question which is all we really need..but wanted to check in and see if there's a cleaner way of doing this which doesn't involve reindexing or leaving these old names around.

Is it something as simple as renaming this key/constraint?

Thanks!

I was half expecting indices created on that column to automatically change with a column rename but that may be too close to magic.